# Run time error on executing the exe manually

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, visual-c++-runtime

I have a Qt application, which runs fine when I execute it from Qt Creator. However, on running it by manually clicking the generated exe, I get the following error :

[image]

I would understand if it would ask for missing DDLs (which I could then place in the same folder). But how should I proceed to handle this (in general) ?

P.S. It is not giving any line number in my source code which I could try testing this assert for. I tried using the release mode as well, but the same error.

Comment: Likely to be the environment difference between Qt creator and the exe dir. Need more detail about the environment config.

Comment: Most likely, something you're doing is failing when you run it "manually" and you're not handling that error properly. Do as it says: press "Retry" to debug. Then examine the call stack, and locate the line in "your" code that was executing when this happened.

Comment: Have you even *tried* entering the debugger? You will initially be placed in the DLL which you do not have access to, *but* you will also be able to walk up the function call stack, and you should do that until you reach your code.

Comment: I did try running it in the debug mode through the QtCreator, and it runs absolutely fine (no warning, no error). When running by manually clicking I get this error and pressing 'Retry','Ignore','Abort' has the same effect, application closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My qml files were not getting deployed properly and thus this error (this assert is probably on the variable storing the main qml file name, i.e. it should not be an empty string, which in case of missing main.qml, it was). Placing the qml files at correct paths solved the issue.

Also, as @mitch has pointed out in his answer, use [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) to find out the dependencies. Although, I have also realized that it doesn't cover all the dependencies (MSVC runtimes for example and other compiler related files sometimes). In that case run the dependency walker and place the missing files manually along with the exe.

Comment: I think that windeployqt should handle as much of the deployment process as possible, and if it's missing something, then it's probably a bug, in which case it would be great if the issue was reported here: bugreports.qt.io. I see that a lot of people are saying that they have to do some parts manually, but I don't think they're giving that feedback to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the problem with your code is; you'll need to use a debugger to find that out. I think that the pre-built Qt libraries that you download come with debug symbols, but if they don't, you can always build Qt yourself to get them using the `-force-debug-info` configure option.

You can also use [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) to see debug output of deployed applications.

However, in general, you should use the [`windeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) tool that is included with Qt.

The [Qt for Windows - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) page has more information about deploying Qt applications to Windows machines, but `windeployqt` should do everything you need.

Comment: I got an idea from you answer and it worked, but I would like to add more to it, would be it fine if I add some more and accept it ?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you did briefly first? :)

Comment: Sure : ) This is how I though about it - IsEmpty() assert is probably coming in coz something is 'empty'/'missing'. So I tried by placing the qml files in the same folder as exe and it started working. Apparently my qmls are not getting deployed properly and thus getting this error. Running it through QtCreator doesn't generate this error though.

Comment: You can probably just create your own answer and accept it, in that case. :)